# Laravel 5.0 ajax message submission returning error or times out

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

Currently, I am attempting to use ajax to send a message (with instant messenger) to the server, save the message and update with the message.  Whenever I submit it, however, it returns a 500 Internal Server Error and if I change the `token:$('#token')` to `'_token' : token` as I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error), it times out completely.

**The ajax**

```
function submitIMchat(){
        console.log($('#IMchat-submit-message').val());
        console.log($('#token').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ action('MessagesController@sendAjaxMessage') }}",
            type: "post",
            dataType:'json',
            data: ({ token:$('#token'), id:{{ Session::get('IMchatuser') }}, message:$('#IMchat-submit-message').val() }),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                return false;
                }

        })
        .error(function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log('server errors',errors);
        });
    };
```

**The form**

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="submitIMchat()">
    <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input id="IMchat-submit-message" type="text" style="width:100%;">
</form>
```

**The route**

```
Route::post('sendAjaxMessage', 'MessagesController@sendAjaxMessage');
```

Can anyone tell what might be wrong with my code here?  If any other information is needed, please let me know.
**Note:** I did not include sendAjaxMessage as it does not execute the function yet.

Thanks.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is probably answering your question. Look up the log files to see more details about what is triggering this error.

Comment: If you haven't even created the sendAjaxMessage method, then that is most likely the problem.

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen I already created it, however, it is not executing it.  Also, the 500 Internal Server Error doesn't have any information with which I can identify the error at. `@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
submitIMchat @ anime:627
onsubmit @ anime:1467`

Comment: Go to your Laravel logs your error will be in there, not in the request payload

Comment: @FabioAntunes I checked it, however, there are no errors dated today in it- last was yesterday when I was working on something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.  It was related to how I was getting my variables in the sendAjaxMessage function: I was treating it like a request when I needed to grab the form values using `Input::all()` and set them as individual variables.  Also, the message sent to the function ended up being saved as $message while the Message object that was created and saved was also named $message.  Thus, `$message->message = $message` would break.