# Laravel 5.2 ajax returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, internal-server-error

My question has been asked and answered here :
[ajax post in laravel 5 return error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error)
But the problem still exists for me.

```
//master.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
...
</head>
```

And create inherits admin that inherits master

```
//create.blade.php
@extends('admin')

@section('head_scripts')
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
            }
        });
        $('#country_id').change(function(){
            $('#province_id').find('option').remove().end();
            $('#province_id').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#city_id').find('option').remove().end();
            $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);
            var cid=$(this).val();
            var params={"type":1, "country_id":cid};
            var paramsString=JSON.stringify(params);
            console.log(paramsString);
            $.ajax({
                url:'/company/ajax',
                type:'POST',
                data:{json: paramsString},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#provinceSelectContainer').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And in the controller :

```
public function ajax(string $params){
    if(!$params) return null;
    $params=json_decode($params);
    return ($params);
}
```

And the route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
    Route::post('/company/ajax', 'CompanyController@ajax');
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please provide the controller method for the same ?

Comment: I added the controller code in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the Laravel 5.2, the middleware has web, api, and auth.
If you want to use ajax sent data, you will use the api middleware with token.
You can see this reference: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {        
    Route::post('api', someController@indexAjax');
});
```

Comment: I placed my ajax route in this, but the error still exists