# 500 error during Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to hit a post route in Laravel and it is giving a 500 error. I tried a different route and it works..
Please note that we have recently added ssl to the site.

the error message in Chrome Dev tools

```
jquery.js:4 POST https://murgency.com/saveRequestInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The HTML code :-

```
<div class="form-group text-right">
                        <a href="" type="button" class="btn-sm-arrowhead" id="dwnBrochure"
                           title="Download Brochure">Download Brochure</a>
                    </div>
```

jquery code :-

```
$('#dwnBrochure').click(function (e) {

        var text_name = $('#txt_name').val();
        var countryCode = $('#countryCode option:selected').text();
        var text_number = $('#txt_number').val();
        var text_email = $('#txt_email').val();
        var package = $('#packagetype').val();
        var type = "agingParents";
        var url = '/saveRequestInfo';

        var data = {
            name: text_name,
            email: text_email,
            countryCode: countryCode,
            phone: text_number,
            package: package,
            type: type
        };

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.status === true) {
                    window.location = "https://murgency.com/home-health-plans/senior/brochure-success";
                }
                else {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('saveRequestInfo', 'ServicesController@saveRequestInfo');
```

ServicesController code:-

```
public function saveRequestInfo(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->input();

        $object = new ParseObject("MedicalRequest");
        $object->set('name', $data['name']);
        $object->set('email', $data['email']);
        $object->set('package', $data['package']);
        $object->set('phone', $data['countryCode'] . $data['phone']);
        $object->set('type', $data['type']);

        try
        {
            $object->save();
            $status = true;
        } catch (ParseException $ex)
        {
            $status = false;
        }

        $this->sendBrochureEmail($data['email'], $data['name']);

        return Response::json(['status' => $status, 'message' => $data['name']]);
    }
```

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error ?

Comment: Check your Laravel/server logs for details on what the 500 was caused by.

Comment: The failure is in the response..I am checking it out..i will confirm in 5-10 minutes..please stick around..

Comment: Hey you can click on the network tab in the console, find this network request and click on preview tab to see the exact error. You will see the error just like the one displayed on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

OThe reason of the error is naturally server side error due to reasons like **syntax error** or **file inclusion related error** or something like that. To debug this you need to know what is the error message produced by PHP and for that check the response of the ajax call.

If nothing found that means the error reporting in your php is off. You can turn it on from php.ini file like this

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

or may be via coding also. Like as follow;

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

or may be via .htaccess file like this;

```
php_flag  display_errors        on
php_value error_reporting       2039
```