# Laravel 5 AJAX search

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I know this question is duplicated but none of them solved my problem. I had an AJAX search which will display all the request of a specific client.

A **client** has many **request** it is a one to many relation.

Now this is I had in my **routes.php**

```
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController',
        ['as' => 'encoder']);
```

I had a resource route which take all 4 http request but the one I am targeting is the **GET/specificResource** with the id being passed in the params.

Now in my show method in **ClientController.php**

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
    {
        $client = $this->clientRepository->with(['request' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])->findWithoutFail($id);

        $keyword = $request->get('keyword');

        if (!$keyword) {
            $client_requests = AnalysisRequest::where('client_id', $client->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        } else {
            $client_requests = AnalysisRequest::where('client_id', $client->id)
            ->OrWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->OrWhere('sample_descrition', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->OrWhere('special_instruction', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        }

        // dd($client_requests);

        if (empty($client)) {
            Flash::error('Client not found');

            return redirect(route('encoder.client.index'));
        }

        return view('encoder-dashboard.client.show', compact('client_requests'))->with('client', $client);
    }
```

Now my **ajax script** below.

```
    @section('scripts')
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.searchbar').on('keyup', function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
          var text = $('#searchbar').val();
          $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              type:"GET",
              url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('.client_id').val(),
              data: {text: $('.searchbar').val()},
              success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
          });
      });
  });
    </script>
@endsection
```

in my **show.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group" id="results">
                            <input type="hidden" id="client_id" value="{{ $client->id }}">
                            <input class="form-control" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @include('encoder-dashboard.client.request')
```

and finally the **request.blade.php**

```
<!-- The timeline -->
  @if (isset($client_requests) && count($client_requests) > 0)
  @foreach($client_requests as $request)
  <ul class="timeline timeline-inverse">
    <!-- timeline time label -->
    <li class="time-label">
          <span class="bg-red">
            {{ $request->created_at->format('M d, Y') }}
          </span>
    </li>
    <!-- /.timeline-label -->
    <!-- timeline item -->
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-edit bg-blue"></i>

      <div class="timeline-item">
        <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $request->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>

        <h3 class="timeline-header">Request Code: <a href="{!! route('encoder.analysis-request.show', $request->id) !!}">{{ $request->reference_no() }}</a>
            @if ($request->rushable == 1)
              <p style="color:red">This request is for RUSH!</p>
            @else
            @endif
        </h3>

        <div class="timeline-body">
          Description: <b>{{ $request->sample_description }}</b>
          <br>
          Service Requested: <b>{{ $request->service->description }}</b>
          <br>
          Category Requested: <b>{{ $request->category->name }}</b>
          <br>
          Method Requested: <b>{{ $request->methodology->name }}</b>
          <br>
          Special Instruction: <b>{{ $request->special_instruction }}</b>
          <br>
          @if ($request->status == 'for_testing')
              Status: <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
          @elseif ($request->status == 'under_analyzation')
              Status: <span class="label label-info">Under Analyzation</span>
          @elseif ($request->status == 'finished')
              Status: <span class="label label-success">Finished</span>
          @endif
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{!! route('encoder.analysis-request.show', $request->id) !!}">Read more</a>
          {{--  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>  --}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  @endforeach
  @endif
```

I figured out the errors and the thing is I still need to hit enter when I search on the input.

I am getting an **500 internal server error**
I already tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error) but still giving me the same error.
Here is the error below.

```
**
```

> jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/encoder/client/1?keyword=4
>   500 (Internal Server Error)
>           send @ jquery.min.js:4
>           ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>           (anonymous) @ 1:437
>           dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>           q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
>           1:446 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
>               at Object.error (1:446)
>               at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>               at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>               at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>               at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

**

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your input box, it does not have class "searchbar"

Comment: It shold be <input class="form-control searchbar" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">

Answer (score 0):

In your ClientController.php

Please change following line:

```
return view('encoder-dashboard.client.show', compact('client_requests'))->with('client', $client);
```

to:

```
echo view('encoder-dashboard.client.show', compact('client_requests'))
    ->with('client', $client)
    ->render();
```

Comment: I edited the question. I also tried that but still not working.

Comment: Please change data: {keyword: $('.searchbar').value()} to data: {keyword: $('#searchbar').value()} as there only id attribute on that element and not class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please try -

```
<input class="form-control searchbar" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
```

You are using class identifier but I think you forgot to add class searchbar in input field.

Comment: Please try  $('#client_id').val() instead of $('#client_id').value()

Comment: It has no error in the console already but still not returning the ajax search :(

Comment: It should return JSON from controller or just change dataType: "html" instead of json

Comment: that didn't work out. I always get an 500 internal server error and I still had to hit enter when searching

Comment: Try 
error: function(data){
                    console.log("No results for " + data + ".");
            }

Comment: still got the same issue.

Comment: I tried this ajax code `$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#searchbar').on('keyup', function(){
          var text = $('#searchbar').val();
          $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              type:"GET",
              url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('#client_id').val(),
              data: {text: $('#searchbar').val()},
              success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
          });
      });
  });` but the response returns me an html of my whole page

Comment: Please return JSON from your controller instead of HTML, replace 
return view('encoder-dashboard.client.show', compact('client_requests'))->with('client', $client);
By 
echo json_encode(array('1','2','3')); exit;
This is just for testing, you can put your original result in place of static array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174657/discussion-between-sachin-vairagi-and-jayz-de-vera).

Comment: wait for a minute

Comment: are u available now?