# Laravel Ajax 500 internal server error when saving data to database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I tried to save form data from ajax, but i am getting a error with 500 internal server error ,here is the code,

home html file :

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('style')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Shift Master</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Shift Id : </label><span class="text-danger">*
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shift_id" id="shift_id" placeholder="Enter ...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Shift Name : </label><span class="text-danger">*
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shift_name" id="shift_name" placeholder="Enter ...">
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <label>Shift Status : </label><span class="text-danger">*
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shift_status" id="shift_status" placeholder="Enter ...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Shift Remark : </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shift_remark" id="shift_remark" placeholder="Enter ...">
                </div>                    
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" onClick ="c();" name="save_shift_master" >Save</button>

          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>
      </div>

@endsection
@section('script')


<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



function c(){
   displayQu();
}
//data table value change

function displayQu(){   

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token]').attr('content')
      }
    });


  var shift_id = $('#shift_id').val();
  var shift_name = $('#shift_name').val();
  var shift_status = $('#shift_status').val();
  var shift_remark = $('#shift_remark').val();

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "{{URL::to('/json-addshiftMaster')}}",
    data:{shift_id:shift_id, shift_name:shift_name, shift_status:shift_status, shift_remark:shift_remark},
    cache: false, 

    success: function(data){

        alert(data.success);

    }
  });
} 
</script>
@endsection
```

web.php :

```
Route::get('/home', 'shiftMasterController@create')->name('shiftMaster');
Route::post('/json-addshiftMaster', 'shiftMasterController@addshift');
```

Controller method :

```
public function addshift()
{

    $table2 = new shift_master_models();
    $table2->shift_id=  Input::get('shift_id');
    $table2->shift_name=  Input::get('shift_name');
    $table2->shift_status=  Input::get('shift_status');
    $table2->shift_remark=  Input::get('shift_remark');

    $table2->save();

    $response = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'msg'    => 'Setting created successfully',
    );

    return Response::json($response);
}
```

Error :

jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/json-addshiftMaster 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
displayQu   @   home:547
c   @   home:529
onclick @   home:349

I am new to Laravel, Hey please help me with this, i can't find a way to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax post in laravel 5 return error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: We're going to need way more than this to be able to help you. That 500 most likely comes from your `shift_master_models` instantiation an/or save, but without a laravel error message, it could quite literally be anywhere. Look at the logs stored in `storage/logs`

Comment: Error in log : local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\shift_master_models' not found' in C:\wamp64\www\LaravelTest\app\Http\Controllers\shiftMasterController.php:55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to import your `shift_master_models()` into the Controller.

Just write it at the top of your controller class:

```
use App\shift_master_models;
```

Be sure the namespace is properly declared in your Model class, like that: `namespace App;` or if it's in the Models folder, just like that: `namespace App\Models;`

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

`$('meta[name="csrf_token]')`

Do you see problem now? It's just a typo. Should be

`$('meta[name="csrf-token"]')`

Comment: I corrected it as $('meta[name="csrf-token"]') ,then this error is coming :  Failed to load resource: json-addshiftMaster:1 the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import you model class in top of the controller class,

```
use App\shift_master_models;
```