# I am sending a post request to my controller in laravel but it is showing 500 error

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am sending an ajax post request to my post controller  but it is showing 500 internal server error

Ajax request in my view with meta tag in head tag.

```
<script src="{{url('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

       }

});
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.like').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
        console.log(isLike);
        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/liked',
          data: {isLiked: isLike, post_id:5}

        });

    });
});
```

POst Controller containing like Post function

```
    public function likePost(Request $request)
    {
        $post_id = $request['post_id'];
        $isLike = $request['isLike'] === 'true';
        $update = false;
        $post = Post::find($post_id);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $like = $user->like()->where('post_id',$post_id)>first();
        if($like)
        {
            $already_liked = $like->isLiked;
            $update = true;
            if($already_liked == $isLike)
            {
                $like->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else{
            $like = new Like();
        }
        $like->isLiked = $isLike;
        $like->user_id = $user->id;
        $like->post_id = $post->id;
        if($update){
            $like->update();
        }
        else{
            $like->save();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can you please help me

Comment: Error 500 is a server generated error. There is some problem in your controller. Post your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below code following

```js
$.ajax({
      url:"{{ route('liked') }}", //router in web.php
      method:"POST", 
      data:{query:query},
      success:function(data){
          //show data to html
         
     }
  });
  
  
//Laravel router web.php
Route::post('/liked','WebController@store')->name('liked');
```

Comment: mine is not a form basically when we click on a link it saves the data in database

Comment: $like = $user->like()->where('post_id',$post_id)>first(); you modify ->first()

Comment: you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error