# Laravel: DataTables warning: table id=laravel_datatable - Ajax error

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am trying to use DataTables for users. I have following different tutorials, most of them using Users table just like I am, so following their steps was easy.
But when I try to load the page I get this error: DataTables warning: table id=laravel_datatable - Ajax error. (which I have attached a photo showing the error and console too).

Photos attached you will also find the View/Routes/Controller functions

What surprises me is that to others is working from comments I have read

Thank you,

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCGLi.png)[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxv1c.png)
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1hvq.png)[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDm6.png)

Comment: Just by looking at your console error it says 500 (internal server error). from what i know it's possible because of the CSRF token please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Thank you, followed that article and now it is looking good. Amazing