# How can I handle the select2 multiple with Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, forms, jquery-select2

I'm trying to show the content of the database into e select2 multiple field.

The field has an id **#ruolo_secondario**

This is the form:

```
{{-- Ruolo secondario --}}
      <div class="col-6">
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple='multiple' name="ruolo_secondario[]" id="ruolo_secondario">
          <option value="1">fonico</option>
          <option value="2">datore luci</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

and this the Ajax

```
          console.log(value.ruolo_secondario);

          $.each(value.ruolo_secondario, function(key, val) {

            $('#ruolo_secondario option[value=' + value.ruolo_secondario + ']').prop('selected', true);
          });
```

When I press the submit button I get a 500 error. Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

90% of the laravel ajax internal server error is due to missing CSRF token, [ajax post in laravel 5 return error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: thank you but I have CSRF set. I get the 500 error ONLY if I fill the multi select2..only in that case